# Does the R stats's resid(x,'type="normalized") functions produce the correct "normalized" model residuals on geeglm fitted objects?

Tags: r, geepack

I ask this because the geepack does not "depend" or import from the stats package according to
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/geepack.pdf.

the stats package has the function residuals(fitted object) and resid(fitted object).

```
residuals {stats}   R Documentation
Extract Model Residuals
Description
residuals is a generic function which extracts model residuals from objects returned by modeling functions.

The abbreviated form resid is an alias for residuals. It is intended to encourage users to access object components through an accessor function rather than by directly referencing an object slot.

All object classes which are returned by model fitting functions should provide a residuals method. (Note that the method is for ‘⁠residuals⁠’ and not ‘⁠resid⁠’.)

Methods can make use of naresid methods to compensate for the omission of missing values. The default, nls and smooth.spline methods do.

Usage
residuals(object, ...)
resid(object, ...)
Arguments
object  
an object for which the extraction of model residuals is meaningful.

... 
other arguments.

Value
Residuals extracted from the object object.

References
Chambers, J. M. and Hastie, T. J. (1992) Statistical Models in S. Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole.

See Also
coefficients, fitted.values, glm, lm.

influence.measures for standardized (rstandard) and studentized (rstudent) residuals
```

geepack has the work-horse GEEGLM